# Minecraft Villager name check

Tags: java, minecraft

I am making a minecraft plugin. When you load this plugin all the villagers with for example the name "priest" need to change to a priest and the name needs to change to what is defined in the config like Father.
this is mijn change of profession and name and a check if custom name is not and is the same as priest

```
if(((Villager) entity).getCustomName() != null && ((Villager) entity).getCustomName().equalsIgnoreCase("priest")){
    ((Villager) entity).setProfession(Profession.PRIEST);
    ((Villager) entity).setCustomName(plugin.getConfig().getString("priest"));
```

does someone know how I can enable this code when you reload/start the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question should go on forums.bukkit.org

That is where minecraft bukkit questions are hosted.

You would use an Entity for loop in onEnable. However things in non loaded chunks will not be touched.